# How can I force user only be able to select multimedia files?

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

The user can select and send me any multimedia files, including images, Pdf, and videos but not executable files. But, they can be a long list of different files with the various extensions. How can I give this access to user by C# in OpenFileDialog box?

Comment: If the user is *sending you* files, I'm guessing he owns the files or has full access to them. Why would you want to forbid him executing them if he wants to? Why would you care? You can filter extensions in the dialog box but that won't stop the user from opening the files he can see.

Comment: @jps ah ok, didn't understand what he was saying. I guess he wanted to say "...but not executable files".

Comment: The filter property of the winforms openfiledialog does filter its extension/filename but it would not check its actual type. An executable file renamed to PDF would be selectable

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the [Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter?view=netcore-3.1) property approriately for the long list of files you want them to be able to select. As you didn't tell us what they are I can only offer an example:

```
dlg.Filter = "Office Files|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt";
```

You can combine specs:

```
dlg.Filter = "Imagey kinda files|*.png;*.jpg;*.gif|Texty kinda files|*.txt;*.log|Just Jpegs|*.jpg|All files|*.*";
```

Every pair of values `"n1|x1|n2|x2..."` forms a "text to show in the filter combo" (n1 etc) / "list of file extensions to show in the file picker" (x1 etc) pair

Setting the filter only affects the files that the OFD shows; a user can just type `*.*` into the filename field and press return and then choose an EXE file anyway. You may need to write code at the back end of whatever is pulling the list of files out of the OFD, to make sure it doesn't process an EXE. Relying on the Filter to absolutely prevent certain files being sent to you is not wise; the user can even rename an EXE and JPG and still send it you.

If the "don't send EXE" is a restriction intended to prevent eg viruses transmission (because you're just going to take what the user picks and send it on verbatim) you'll have to actually look at the bytes of what files the user chooses and make sure it matches what the name claims. (For that you'll have to look up file structures etc.. For example JPEGs have the text "JFIF" at bytes 6-10, programs typically start with bytes "MZ", zip files start with "PK" etc).

If it's just to prevent garbage because these files are going to be fed into a resizing routine, just catch any exceptions the routine throws and ignore the bad file. It's still helpful to the user to know what they can upload though, so I'd still have the filter, but just silently ignore any crap they send